# Cascading drop down in table using Angular 4 typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am new to angular and developing my very first application using angular 4 and typescript

I want to use Cascading drop-down in table using angular4

Currently, I have been working on it but when I change drop down from the first row it is a binding second level dropdown for all row.

I want to bind the second level drop down of the row from the first level drop down is changed.

I have some idea on my mind to achieve this but I guess It might be a patch so I am very curious to know any proper way of angular to achieve this.

ts file code

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Category } from '../model/Category';
import { SubCategory } from '../model/subCategory';
import { Partner } from '../model/partner';
import { GetdataService } from '../../../../Server/api/Getdata.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'UploadFile.component.html'
})
export class UploadFileComponent implements OnInit {
  AllCategoryList: Category[] = [];
  AllSubCategoryList: SubCategory[] = [];
  constructor(private _datatask: GetdataService, private _router: Router) { }

  onChangeCategory(deviceValue) {         
    if (deviceValue > 0) {
      this._datatask.getAllSubCategory(deviceValue).subscribe(
        (data: SubCategory[]) => {
          this.AllSubCategoryList = data;
        }
      );
      console.log("from component: " + deviceValue);
    }
    else
      {
        //clear dropdown...
        this.AllSubCategoryList= [];        
      }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._datatask.getAllCategory().subscribe(
      (data: Category[]) => {
        this.AllCategoryList = data;
      }
    );

    this._datatask.getAllPartner().subscribe(
      (data: Partner[]) => {
        this.AllPartnerList = data;
      }
    );
  }  
}
```

HTML file

```
<div>
  <table width="100%" border="1">
    <thead>     
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>SubCategory</th>
      <th>Partner</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let transaction of transactions">
      <tr>       
        <td>
          <select style="Width:100px;" (change)="onChangeCategory($event.target.value)" >
            <option value=0>--Select--</option>
                <option  value="{{item.ID}}"  *ngFor="let item of AllCategoryList" [ngValue]="item.ID" >{{item.Category}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select style="Width:100px;">
            <option value=0>--Select--</option>
                 <option  *ngFor="let item of AllSubCategoryList" [ngValue]="item.ID" >{{item.SubCategory}}</option> 
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select style="Width:100px;">
            <option value=0>--Select--</option>
                <option  *ngFor="let item of AllPartnerList" [ngValue]="item.ID" >{{item.PartnerName}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you needed an array of states... (in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BkDk9wLB3J5Uv2ijEX6i?p=preview) you listed in the comments below).
You can probably apply same to your code in original question.

list-component.ts tweaks

```
export class CountryListComponent {

  states: State[] = [[] as State[],[] as State[],[] as State[]] 

  onSelect(value,index) {
    this.states[index] = this._dataService.getStates().
      filter((item)=> item.countryid == value);
  }
}
```

list-component.html tweak

- **Updated:** after [this exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469363/selecting-default-in-select-option/45469511) with @GünterZöchbauer :
- Use (ngModelChange) over (change)

---

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry[number].id"
    (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event, number)">
```

[Fixed Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dIS2GJdcA8OiPZU4jD4C?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply...But if you can explain what you are asking to do...I am not able to get what you are asking to do

Comment: Okay...Let me try with that

Comment: sorry JGFMK, but your solution is not working for me.

Comment: If you post a Plunker of what you've got, I'll take a look.

Comment: @JGFMK : i have seen your solution but it's not working for me,also i have created Plunker regarding this. In this one can change first country from first row then binding state regarding in second whole column's dropdown insted  of first one.any help..?http://plnkr.co/edit/BkDk9wLB3J5Uv2ijEX6i?p=preview

Comment: @ JGFMK, Looked at your solution and it looks promising, let me try it with my code.

Comment: I just this second tweaked the states: declaration and updated the Plunker link.  Both worked, but I think the latest  is a better representation of the array content.

Comment: Okay got it..:) I will try with latest one.:)

Comment: @JGFMK : how to validation on this type of binding any idea..?

Comment: @GhanshyamLakhani These were drop down lists. So possible values are pre-configured. So I'm not sure what your asking...

Comment: @MiteshGadhiya - I made another tweak to answer after some feedback from someone else...

Comment: Okay..I got the point..I will update my code accordingly...:) Thanks for insights..

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced this problem and finally got a solution using custom pipe.

make a filter in external file like - mycustomfilter.ts

**mycustomfilter.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myCustomFilter',
    pure: false
})
export class myCustomFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], field : string, value): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!value || value.length === 0) return items;
    return items.filter(it =>
    it[field] === value);
  }
}
```

**declarations** in app module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, myCustomFilterPipe],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

**item-order.component.ts**

```
categoryList=[{id:1,name:'Office Stationery'},
              {id:2,name:'Grocery'}
        ];
itemList=[
         {id:1,name:'Pen',categoryID:1},
         {id:2,name:'A4 Peper',categoryID:1},
         {id:3,name:'Oil',categoryID:2},
         {id:4,name:'Sugar',categoryID:2}
    ];
```

**item-order.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let order of o.controls; let i = index" [formGroup]="order" class="form-row">
              
<td>
<select class="form-control" formControlName="ItemCategoryID">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option *ngFor="let s of categoryList" [ngValue]="s.id">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select class="form-control" formControlName="ItemID">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option *ngFor="let s of itemList | myCustomFilter : 'categoryID' : order.value.ItemCategoryID" [ngValue]="s.id">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```