# Selecting default in select option

Tags: html, angular

In my Angular program, I have a select box that uses an `ngFor` to display many employees and uses the `ngValue` and `ngModel` to take the number of employee from the list and use it as an index when accessing an array. I want to have an option above all of the employees that's selected. Here's what I've tried, everything works whenever All Employees or one of the employees is chosen, but I want the default to be the All Employees option. How can I do that?

`HTML`:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">
    <option selected>All Employees</option>
    <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">{{emp.EmpID}} - {{emp.FirstName}} {{emp.LastName}}</option>
</select>
```

and here's the variable in my ts:

```js
selectedEmployee: number;
```

I've tried these two ways:

```html
<option selected>All Employees</option>
```

```html
<option selected="selected">All Employees</option>
```

but neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee"
```

```
class MyComponent {
  selectedEmployee:number = 3;
```

You can use

```
 (ngModelChange)="updateSelection($event)"
```

```
 updateSelection(value) {
   this.model.employeeNo = value;
 }
```

Comment: and that will have the default option selected as "All Employees"?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. Use   `<option [ngValue]="-1">All Employees</option>` and set `selectedEmployee` to `-1`

Comment: how can I take in the value into the (ngModelChange)? I'm just getting an error that says `Parameter 'value' implicityly has an 'any' type`

Comment: That doesn't sound like an error. Xou can try `...(value:number) { ...`

Comment: Don't you want (ngModelChange)="updateSelection($event.target.value)" ???

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer okay, that fixed that but it still isn't setting "All Employees" as the default. I have `<select class="form-control" id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee" (ngModelChange)="updateSelection($event)">
              <option selected [ngValue]="-1">All Employees</option>
              <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">{{emp.EmpID}} - {{emp.FirstName}} {{emp.LastName}}</option>
            </select>` and `   updateSelection(value: number) {
        this.selectedEmployee = value; 
    }`

Comment: No, `(ngModelChange)` is an `@Output()` from the `ngModel` directive, not a DOM event

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Who was 'No' targetted at? asdf or me ?

Comment: @asdf Remove `selected`, I forgot to remove it in my comment initially bit removed it 2 minites later. Did you set `selectedEmployee` to `-1`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - this.model??? Is this some sort of baked in property when your component uses ngModel?

Comment: @JGFMK no, only when you use `[(ngModel)]="model"`, but you can use any other name.

Comment: @JGFMK no, only when you use `[(ngModel)]="model"`, but you can use any other name.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer whenever I have `selectedEmployee` set to `-1` I get multiple errors in my console that are related to trying to display the data associated with it. it's probably something on my end. thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ngModel and just get the employee when changes. In this example the all employees is always the selected option and you only retrieve the employee when select changes.

```
<select (change)="updateEmployee($event.target.value)" >
        <option [value]="'All employees'" ></option>
        <template ngFor let-emp [ngForOf]="emplInfo" let-i="index">
          <option [value]="i" >{{emp.empId}}</option>
        </template>
    </select>
```

Comment: I would like the value to be the index of whichever employee was selected though

Comment: there is no need for the template tag, and if there were, `<ng-template>` would be a better option

Comment: @asdf I have updated the answer setting the index as the value. Hope that helps. Yeah, now is ng-template, template alone is been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
  <label>Employee:</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="employee.id"
    (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)">
      <option value="0">--Select--</option>
      <option *ngFor="#employee of employees" 
        value={{employee.id}}>{{employee.name}}</option>
```

```
onSelect(value) {
 this.employee.id = value;
}
```

Comment: `(change)` together with `ngModel` is usually a bad idea because this event fires before `selectedCountry` was updated, `'ngModelChange)` is usually a bezter option

Comment: Thanks for insights @GünterZöchbauer Updated code accordingly